# Host socket appears as directory in Docker volume

Tags: docker, containers, volume, docker-stack

I have a constraint to use unix domain socket for communication between a Docker container and a process on the host machine.
The socket on the host machine resides in `/tmp/my_socket`.

For that, I am running the docker container with the mounted volume as such:
`docker run <image> -v /tmp/my_socket:/tmp/my_socket`

But I noticed that the container fails to communicate with the socket, so I connected to the container and noticed that the socket is marked as a directory instead of a socket for some reason:
`drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root`

**Why is the socket mounted as a directory?**

I suspect that might be why the container cannot connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Unix **mount**(2) system call only mounts directories.  This has implications on Docker's container filesystem setup: normally the thing you mount into a container is a directory, but Docker can do some magic for plain files which can be a little fragile at times.  A socket is neither a directory nor a plain file so directly mounting it might not work well.

I'd try to reconfigure the server to put its socket in a dedicated directory (a subdirectory of `/var/run` would be common).  Then you can bind-mount that entire directory into the client container.

```bash
sudo mkdir /var/run/my_app/my_socket
sudo my_server --daemon --socket-path /var/run/my_app/my_socket

sudo docker run \
  -d \
  -v /var/run/my_app:/var/run/my_app \
  -e SOCKET_PATH=/var/run/my_app/my_socket \
  my/client
```

This won't work at all if Docker is inside a VM (including if you're using a Docker Desktop setup or if your Docker is explicitly inside a VM, maybe using minikube or a similar distribution).  Unix sockets never cross OS/VM boundaries.

Comment: How is that different than just mounting in my case the `/tmp/` directory? (`docker run <image> -v /tmp/:/tmp/`)
Because in that case it fails with the same reason, the socket is marked as a directory.